# Can HtmlAgility be used to fetch from Html source containing PHP code?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a PHP source file, so it has both PHP and HTML code. Now I have to find whether the PHP variable is used inside a Html Element directly or as an Html Attribute value. Initially, I though Regex can help... but was unable to design the pattern as there may be several scenarios.

As HtmlAgility is a Html parser, will it able to perform the task? After searching a while, I'm still not able to figure it out!

P.S: I am processing PHP source code as text file in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the web server will execute the PHP rendering HTML, JavaScript etc and supply that to whatever HTTP client is making the request.

So the point is, by the time you request the PHP and get a response back, it's no longer the raw PHP code. For that you'd have to have direct access to the web server, or some other mechanism.